# SQL Join Query doesn't work in PowerShell

Tags: sql, powershell, join, oledbconnection

I am trying to convert a Python script into a PS Script. The script reads an access database file and runs a simple query to send the results to a CSV file. The query is executed without problems from Python and also directly from MS Access.

Query:

```
SELECT
  TABLEA.SITE_CODE,
  TABLEB.REG_TITLE,
  TABLEC.G_ORG_TITLE,
  TABLED.BRD_TITLE,
  TABLEA.SITE_TYPE
FROM ((TABLEA
  LEFT JOIN [TABLEC] ON TABLEA.[G_ORG_ID] = TABLEC.[ID])
  LEFT JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEA.[REGION_ID] = TABLEB.[ID])
  LEFT JOIN TABLED ON TABLEA.[BRAND_ID] = TABLED.[ID]
ORDER BY TABLEA.SITE_CODE
```

This is the code that I am using:

```
$path = "\Path\to\File.mdb"
$QuerySites = "SELECT TABLEA.SITE_CODE, TABLEB.REG_TITLE, TABLEC.G_ORG_TITLE, TABLED.BRD_TITLE, TABLEA.SITE_TYPE FROM ((TABLEA LEFT JOIN [TABLEC] ON TABLEA.[G_ORG_ID] = TABLEC.[ID]) LEFT JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEA.[REGION_ID] = TABLEB.[ID]) LEFT JOIN TABLED ON TABLEA.[BRAND_ID] = TABLED.[ID] ORDER BY TABLEA.SITE_CODE"

$csv = "C:\path\Outfile.csv"
$connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= $path"

$delimiter = ','

$command2 = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command2.CommandText = $QuerySites
$adapter2 = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter $command2
$dataset2 = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataSet
$adapter2.Fill($dataset2)




$connection.Close()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)."
At line:14 char:1
+ $adapter2.Fill($dataset2)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OleDbException
```

As I said, the query runs without problems in the Python script and directly from Access.

I have not found resources that guide me to the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose all of your table and field names in brackets for keyword safety.

```
SELECT
    [TABLEA].[SITE_CODE],
    [TABLEB].[REG_TITLE],
    [TABLEC].[G_ORG_TITLE],
    [TABLED].[BRD_TITLE],
    [TABLEA].[SITE_TYPE]
FROM (([TABLEA]
    LEFT JOIN [TABLEC] ON [TABLEA].[G_ORG_ID] = [TABLEC].[ID])
    LEFT JOIN [TABLEB] ON [TABLEA].[REGION_ID] = [TABLEB].[ID])
    LEFT JOIN [TABLED] ON [TABLEA].[BRAND_ID] = [TABLED].[ID]
ORDER BY [TABLEA].[SITE_CODE]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Although this may be a good general practice, I don't see any special characters or keywords that would be addressed by the brackets.